# No audio after watermark FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to watermark a video with images (png). The watermark works fine. However I don't have audio

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i watermark_template_bottom.png -i watermark_template_top.png -filter_complex [1:0]fade=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=14:d=2:alpha=1[v_0];
    [1:0]fade=in:st=28:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=42:d=2:alpha=1[v_1];
    [1:0]fade=in:st=56:d=2:alpha=1[v_2];[v_0][v_1]overlay[ovl_0];[ovl_0][v_2]overlay[ovl_1];
    [ovl_1][2:0]overlay[end];[0:0] [end]overlay=eof_action=pass[out] -map [out] out.mp4
```

Is there a problem on my code?

Answer (score 5):

Remove `-map [out]`  **or** add `-map 0:a`. By setting one map, default auto-mapping is disabled, so only the expressly mapped streams are processed.

And you can add `-acodec copy` if you don't wish to re-encode the audio.

Answer (score 3):

Add `-acodec copy` to your command to *copy the audio stream*.

> https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy
>
> Stream copy is a mode selected by supplying the copy parameter to the
>   -codec option. It makes ffmpeg omit the decoding and encoding step for the specified stream, so it does only demuxing and muxing. It is
>   useful for changing the container format or modifying container-level
>   metadata.